# Need help to find, move/copy with a bat file particular files to a new folder

Tags: excel, batch-file

Sorry, I'm no code cutter and my '*basic*' skills have been on hold for some time, so I really need some help here to run a (hopefully simple) .bat file to find, compare and copy files from one folder to another.

The setup...
I have an Excel spreadsheet that has approx 740 unique part numbers (for car parts) in a list/column (but each part number is a number only which does not have/include a '.jpg' suffix).

I also have a folder with approx over 14,000 '.jpg' files that have file names (and the '.jpg' suffix) that may match some of these Excel part numbers.

I want to take the 740 unique part numbers (that do not have a '.jpg' suffix) from the Excel file and run a script that checks/finds whether each Excel number has a match in the 14,000 '.jpg' files folder and if so, to then copy or move that '.jpg' file to a new folder so it reduces the picture files down to only the ones needed to be viewed and checked for possible use.

Can this be done with a simple batch file and if so, would someone out there be able to suggest or help to get this to work.

Many thanks, lexip

Comment: 1) batch can't read Excel files (but can handle `.csv`), so you have to convert your Excel list. 2) to read the `.csv`, use a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop. Come up with some code, so we can help you with it.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. Having said that, I suggest to use a script language which supports to open Excel as a com-object (J-/vbscript/powershell) or can read `.xls(x)` directly/with a module ([DougFinke's Import-Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33225601/6811411)

Comment: Another approach is to copy the 14,000 filenames in another column in your Excel sheet and use Excel search capabilities for finding the matches.